# Forwarding in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, controller, forwarding

In Java Servlets/JSP you can redirect (round trip to server) request or forward request (in scope of the same request). It seems that Rails docs only have examples of redirecting. How can I implement forwarding in Rails 3? Thanks advance.

Comment: isn't forwarding and redirecting two words for the same job?~

Comment: No forwarding is not redirecting. Maybe you can use same method for both cases in Rails, but I don't know how. Can you provide examples of redirecting (30x) and forwarding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3810690

Workaround seems to be creating a wrapper for the controller logic and calling it from both actions, while rendering a shared template. Not exactly ideal, but will at least DRY you up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If the action you are trying to forward to is in the same controller and requires the same parameters, you could just call the instance method directly.